# Some cell is not display in tcpdf

Tags: php, dynamic, html-table, tcpdf

I am creating dynamic table using tcpdf, but I am not getting the table properly. I just got first cell of each row only, other cell will not display and also table border is disappear. How can I fix it?

```
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Write(0, 'Example of HTML tables', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
$pdf->setPageMark();

$pdfArray = array();
$str2 = "<table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' border='1'><tr><td colspan='6'>".$br1."  ". $sem1."</td></tr>";

$i=1;
$str2 .="<tr>";
while($i<=42)
{
$str2 .="<td>"."  ".$i."</td>";
if($i%6==0)
  $str2 .="</tr><tr>";
$i++;
}
$str2 .= "</tr></table>";

array_push($pdfArray, $str2);
$table = implode(" ",$pdfArray);
$tbl100 = <<<EOD
$table
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($str2, true, false, false, false, '');
```

It will give output like

```
 1
 7
 13
 19
 25
 31
```

But I want output like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 ...
25 26 ...
31 32 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<td colspan='7'>` and `if($i%6==0)` does not match, but you should check out the `while($f1 = mysql_fetch_row($res))` expression, too. (`mysql_fetch_array()` recommended)

**Edit:**

I found a comment in the TCPDF source:

```
NOTE: all the HTML attributes must be enclosed in double-quote.
```

So this should work aright:

```
$str2 = '<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="1" border="10"><tr><td colspan="7">'.$br1.'  '. $sem1.'</td></tr>';
```

Comment: NOT HELPFUL. i am crating time table, in which first column is per-1, per-2 etc. and six period that's why colspan=7 and $i%6==0

Comment: echo $str2 work very fine but i want to convert $str2 in to pdf. That's why i used tcpdf. HTML code work very well.

Comment: Well, TCPDF is not a browser. :)

Comment: Stocki now i edit code, paste it and solved this. Thanks in advance.